# Can anyone help me fix the fact that re-routing to Ireland stops inbound phone calls working?

Tags: twilio, sip, voip, pjsip, sip-server

I currently have Twilio set up with FreePBX. It is working great and i am very happy with it.

The only problem I have right now is the fact that Twilio uses United States for routing. My business where we are using the phone system is in Ireland (I am an end user not a reseller). We will be mainly calling Irish and UK numbers.

If we are calling Irish numbers from Ireland, but the 'routing' is done through a US server, that will probably add latency (**note: I currently do not notice any major latency problems, but I assume it would be even better audio when routed through Ireland?**

I am having some issues with this. I changed routing to Ireland, made a new SIP Trunk for Ireland, made new credentials, and put in my new SIP Termination URI for my new Ireland Trunk into FreePBX and my new credentials.

However, I can only MAKE outbound calls. I cannot receive inbound calls.

I will see for now, how it goes. We might be able to stay with US routing. Do you guys know if there are any problems with US routing? Currently we don't notice much of a problem, but what about billing? Will it cost us more to route through US?

Edit: one consequence is that when an irish phone number rings our business, it shows up as: 01135389XXXXXXX instead of 0894875848, because it is being routed through america, it is being changed into E.164 format and then the 011 american international number is added to it

Thank you.

Lorcan

Answer (score -1):

> However, I can only MAKE outbound calls. I cannot receive inbound calls.

Have you reconfigured your phone number within Twilio to direct inbound calls to the new SIP trunk that you created?

> Do you guys know if there are any problems with US routing?

No, US routing was working for you and it works, there aren't any problems with it.

> Currently we don't notice much of a problem, but what about billing? Will it cost us more to route through US?

[SIP trunk pricing is here](https://www.twilio.com/sip-trunking/pricing/ie). There's no difference in cost to route through the US, but there are different costs for higher calls per second depending on the region you are using. For example, in ie1 2 calls per second costs $25 a month, but in us1 or us2 that is only $15 a month.

Comment: "Have you reconfigured your phone number within Twilio to direct inbound calls to the new SIP trunk that you created?" Yes I have, it is rerouted to Ireland

I go active numbers -> my number -> reroute to IE1
Then on the right, under Active Configuration, it says (SIP Trunk: (my Irish sip trunk)

I guess I could just use US routing but it seems a bit crazy long term to be routing everything through US from Ireland

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that number config, please?